# ENAMETOOLONG tailwinds yarn

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, hadoop-yarn

I'm getting ENAMETOOLONG when using yarn run, seems like run looks for files within nested folders

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', 
            '../../packages/common/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  ...
```

yarn start should work

Comment: `**` tells it you want it to recurse. Don't use that in your paths if you don't _want_ it to search nested folders.

Comment: That said, any chance you might have a recursive symlink or a symlink loop in the tree being searched? That's an easy way to get into this state even if, ignoring symlinks, your paths are all in an acceptable length.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwinds looks for the filetypes specified on the Configuring source file tailwind.config.js
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
if the path points to a directory where the node modules exist there might be aliases within the node modules sub paths pointing to the root of the path, this will cause tailwinds to continue (looking for matching files) on an infinite loop down the directory tree.

The solution is to point tailwinds to a path where no aliases to itself exist:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
            '../../packages/common/dist/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
...
```